# Unable to use TypeScript server side with node.js (Inheritance only)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I don't understand why inheritance in TS is so tricky. It doesn't works on my 'Controllers'. I tried to compile with both AMD and commonJS, same result.

***UserController***

```
///<reference path='../../../../shared/lib/public/def/defLoader.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='Controller.ts'/>

import express = require("express");
import controller = require("./Controller");

export class UserController extends controller.Controller{

    public constructor(req: express.Request, res: express.Response){
        super();
    }

    public  __before(){
        console.log('before');
    }

    public  __repartitor(){
        console.log('repartitor');
    }

    public  test(){
        console.log('test');
    }

    public  default(){
        console.log('default');
    }

}
```

***Controller*** (parent)

```
///<reference path='../../../../shared/lib/public/def/defLoader.d.ts'/>
import express = require("express");

export class Controller{

    public static beforeSharedPath: string = path.join(__dirname, "../../public");
    public static publicPath: string = path.join(__dirname, '../../');
    public static sharedPath: string = Controller.beforeSharedPath+"/shared";
    public static webServerPath: string = path.join(__dirname, '../../');

    public req: express.Request;
    public res: express.Response;

    public constructor(req: express.Request, res: express.Response){
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
    }

    public static __before(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function){
        next();
    }

    public static __after(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function){
        next();
    }

}
```

In another script:

```
 var obj = require('./../app/controllers/' + controllerName+".js")
```

The previous code call:

```
module.exports = require('./ts/UserController.ts').UserController;
```

But I got a **obj** undefined. If I remove the extends and call() I got the object.
I just don't understand, I tried to fix it 3 hours without get any good result.

There is some tutorial to use TS on nodejs server side? ...
I use TS somewhere else and it works for both server + client with the same code, but it's the same, when I extends I got troubles.

Comment: On server side it looks like we should add both reference using the "///" and import&require the class/interface we want to inherit. I did something that works today. But I'm not sure at all there is nothing more... Surprise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UserController` and `Controller` code is valid and it should work.

Error seems to be in `var obj = require('./../app/controllers/' + controllerName+".js")` You should not need the `js` extension.

Comment: I remember I tried with and without the extension but no change I guess, the fact is I completely changed this part of the code and I use sails.js inside my application to have a powerful MVC pattern.